# AutoMapperMappingException - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

When I implemented `IReadOnlyList` in my code, my unit test threw an `AutoMapperMappingException`.

From digging through articles and documentation, my guess is that AutoMapper needs special coding for `readonly` types.  What would this look like?

Note: I tried `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` as another post suggested, but no improvements.

> Test Name:    CreateOrder_ValidContract_CreatesNewOrder Test
>   FullName: ACME.Maintenance.Domain.Test.OrderServiceTest.CreateOrder_ValidContract_CreatesNewOrder
>   Test Source:  C:\Users\me\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ACME.Maintenance\ACME.Maintenance.Domain.Test\OrderServiceTest.cs
>   : line 65 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.0233941
>
> Result StackTrace:     at lambda_method(Closure , ContractDto , Contract
>   , ResolutionContext )    at
>   ACME.Maintenance.Domain.ContractService.GetById(String contractId) in
>   C:\Users\me\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ACME.Maintenance\ACME.Maintenance.Domain\ContractService.cs:line
>   34    at
>   ACME.Maintenance.Domain.Test.OrderServiceTest.CreateOrder_ValidContract_CreatesNewOrder()
>   in C:\Users\me\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ACME.Maintenance\ACME.Maintenance.Domain.Test\OrderServiceTest.cs:line
>   69 Result Message:     Test method
>   ACME.Maintenance.Domain.Test.OrderServiceTest.CreateOrder_ValidContract_CreatesNewOrder
>   threw exception:  AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type
>   map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: ContractDto -> Contract
>
> ACME.Maintenance.Domain.DTO.ContractDto -> ACME.Maintenance.Domain.Contract

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ContractDto, Contract>());
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<PartDto, Part>());
[TestMethod]
public void CreateOrder_ValidContract_CreatesNewOrder()
    {
        //Arrange
        var orderService = new OrderService();
        var contractService = new ContractService(_contractRepository);
        var contract = contractService.GetById(ValidContractId);

        // Act
        var newOrder = orderService.CreateOrder(contract);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(newOrder, typeof(Order));

        Guid guidOut;
        Assert.IsTrue(Guid.TryParse(newOrder.OrderId, out guidOut));

        Assert.AreEqual(newOrder.Status, ContractStatus.New);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(newOrder.Items, typeof(IReadOnlyList<OrderItem>));

    }
```

ContractService class:

```
public Contract GetById(string contractId)
    {
        var contractDto = _contractRepository.GetById(contractId);
        var contract = Mapper.Map<ContractDto, Contract>(contractDto);
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        return contract;
    }
```

Contract class:

```
public class Contract
{
    public string ContractId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

}
```

ContractDto class:

```
public class ContractDto
{
    public string ContractId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Please show the full text of the exception - which will contain information about what the mismapping is - and your classes.

Comment: Updated original post with full exception and classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `Mapping.Initialize` multiple times: it is not additive, so you are overwriting the previous mappings, and that's why you are losing the map from `ContractDto` to `Contract`

So in the `Setup` method of your test, you should call it like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
     cfg.CreateMap<ContractDto, Contract>();
     cfg.CreateMap<PartDto, Part>();
});
```